# Apache doesn't process localhost path html file

Tags: apache

I am newbie working with html/css. The problem I encounter is, I can access my html file using localhost and other path. But one  of the path doesn't load css file correctly.

**file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/classes/index.html**
The above path works fine and loads everything correctly but

localhost/classes/index.html

Doesn't load the index.html file correctly.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post your html?

Comment: You might also think about using Firebug with firefox or Chrome developer tools of you use Google Chrome to find out what the browser is doing. Go read your webserver log files too,

Comment: The website html/css/bootstrap code works fine. I think the problem is with apache server. It does not load css file while using localhost/classes/index.html path.